# Ember/emberfire run loop acceptance test

Tags: ember.js, emberfire

So my acceptance test keeps on destroying itself before my promise finishes. I'm aware that I need to wrap my promise in Ember run loop but I just can't get it to work. Here's how my component looks:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  didReceiveAttrs() {
    this.handleSearchQueryChange();
  },

  /**
   * Search based on the searchQuery
   */
  handleSearchQueryChange() {
    this.get('store').query('animals', {
      orderBy: 'name',
      startAt: this.attrs.searchQuery
    }).then(searchResults => {
      this.set('searchResults', searchResults);
    });
  }
});
```

I've already tried wrapping `this.handleSearchQueryChange()`, `this.get('store').query...` and `this.set('searchResults', searchResults)` in a run loop but still, the acceptance test just doesn't wait for store.query to finish.

One thing to note that this store query performs a request on a live Firebase back-end.

I'm currently using Pretender to mock the data and solve this issue. But I'd like to solve it through Ember.run as well. Anyone care to provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem may have the same cause as the [errors I've been seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426242/ember-js-acceptance-testing-not-waiting-for-asynchronous-data-operations)

tl;dr

To work around this issue, I've been using a [custom test waiter.](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-cli-test-model-waiter) You can install it with `ember install ember-cli-test-model-waiter` (for Ember v2.0+) and it should just make your test work without any further setup (if not, please [file a bug](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-cli-test-model-waiter/issues)).

Longer answer:

The root cause of this problem is that the ember testing system doesn't know how to handle Firebase's asynchronicity.  With most adapters, this isn't a problem, because the testing system [instruments AJAX calls](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e88c64460888f8669a63419493d27226b6131668/packages/ember-testing/lib/setup_for_testing.js#L8) and [ensures they have completed before proceeding](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e88c64460888f8669a63419493d27226b6131668/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L226), but this doesn't work with Firebase's websockets communication.

The [custom test waiter I mentioned above](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-cli-test-model-waiter) works by waiting for all models to resolve before proceeding with the test, and so should work with any non-AJAX adapter.

Comment: Thanks I was afraid that I'd get that long answer. Oh well.

Like I said, I'm currently working around this by using pretender but ideally I'd like to use it on a running test database in Firebase so that I could also test out my security rules. I'll look into your addon when I'm able to. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I wrote the waiter for exactly that reason: wanting to test against a live (test instance) firebase. Just installing it should be all that's needed to make your tests work (if not, please let me know). Another option that I haven't looked into too much is [firebase-server](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server) -- it's [promoted by firebase as an official solution for end-to-end testing](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-04-24-end-to-end-testing-firebase-server.html)

Comment: Actually, that's not quite true if you need your test to go through the firebase login process. There's still a (related) bug blocking that. I've filed [a pull request to fix it](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/pull/330), but until that lands you'll need a little manual bookkeeping around the login: https://github.com/gabrielgrant/empty/commit/257776d32dc300f0c0dde8d2904274172e2067d5

Comment: For sign in, I'm currently using Torii's built-in test-helper for stubbing sessions during acceptance tests. That way I could easily test session-based scenarios. I haven't tested it on a live firebase though, only in a pretender. Though I'm expecting it seamlessly work with it and your addon.

Comment: Yes, that should work to get things running; I wanted to use the actual login so I could test my real security rules