# Ember.js Acceptance Testing not waiting for asynchronous data operations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

When using the Emberfire (Firebase) adapter, I'm getting various errors that indicate the tests are not waiting for data operations to complete.

eg: `Error: Assertion Failed: You can only unload a record which is not inFlight.` when I try to create, check, and then delete a record

Also:

`FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Called stop() outside of a test context at Object.extend.stop (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:3000:10) at exports.default._emberTestingAdaptersAdapter.default.extend.asyncStart`

These errors do not occur while manually navigating through my app, nor when using the standard ember data adapter.

What is causing these errors and how do I avoid them?

Edit: although the symptoms are a bit different (no error thrown), it sounds like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088175/ember-emberfire-run-loop-acceptance-test/33426343#33426343) may have the same root cause as the errors I've been seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr

To work around the issue, I've been using a [custom test waiter.](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-cli-test-model-waiter) You can install it with `ember install ember-cli-test-model-waiter` (works with Ember v2.0+)

Longer answer:

The root cause of these problems is that the ember testing system doesn't know how to handle Firebase's asynchronicity.  With most adapters, this isn't a problem, because the testing system [instruments AJAX calls](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e88c64460888f8669a63419493d27226b6131668/packages/ember-testing/lib/setup_for_testing.js#L8) and [ensures they have completed before proceeding](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e88c64460888f8669a63419493d27226b6131668/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers.js#L226), but this doesn't work with Firebase's websockets communication.

So although these errors don't occur when interacting manually, I believe they technically could if it were possible to click fast enough.

These problems are [known to occur with ember-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/ember-pouch/issues/27) and will likely also occur with other non-AJAX adapters (eg. localstorage adapters ([1](https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter), [2](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage)), or any other websockets-based adapter. It may occur with the fixture adapter, but that may return results immediately and so not trigger this problem). It also happens with other asynchronous processes, like [liquid-fire animations](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/issues/29) ([fixed in a similar way](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/commit/dc59d52af710d9fd30c5cb945af2627ca0a93936))

The [custom test waiter I mentioned in the tl;dr](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-cli-test-model-waiter) works by waiting for all models to resolve before proceeding with the test, and so should work with all of these non-AJAX adapters.

For more background on how ember's testing deals with asynchronicity under the hood, [Cory Forsyth has a helpful blog post](http://coryforsyth.com/2014/07/10/demystifing-ember-async-testing/), and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/foxnewsnetwork/727f47e6bb480390e98d#my-solution) gives another more flexible solution approach but that requires more manual book-keeping.